# How to prevent Coverpage and Tableofcontents to set margin

Tags: margins, geometry

I set the margin like this:

```
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, outer=1.5cm, inner=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

But on the first two pages (Coverpage + TableOfContents), I want to have the same margin on the left and right side.

How can I do this?

Comment: you can try `\newgeometry{hmargin=2cm}
coverpage and toc
\restoregeometry
\clearpage`

Comment: @touhami: Where do I write this?

Comment: normally just after `begin{document}`. Please add a minimale example of your document.

Comment: @touhami: I don't get it. I thought I have to add the lines before the coverpage and some after it? Or not?

Comment: `\newgeometry{hmargin=2cm}` before coverpage +tableofcontents and `\restoregeometry \clearpage` after.